# How to add multiple images to a custom post type without plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, images, uploads, gallery

I have created a custom post type and I need to add multiple images not in editor ..
Is there a simple tuto can help me ..??
thnx ..

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing something like this? I hope it will help:
https://www.skyverge.com/blog/custom-post-type-with-image-uploads/

Answer (score 2):

Using custom post meta box .
[Visit this link](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/attaching-files-to-your-posts-using-wordpress-custom-meta-boxes-part-1--wp-22291)

Comment: This only adds a single image to the post.